# How do I write into a file in a new line using python?

Tags: python, debian

I am trying to make a script that will write new aliases into bashrc, However when I run the scrip it either writes in the first line or in the last line.My script is fairly simple:

```
with open ("/user/.bashrc","a+") as f1:
   f1.write(new_alias + " " + alias_command)
   f1.seek(0,0)               # This writes in the first line and (1,0) writes in the last
   command = f1.read()
   print command              # To show me the input without getting into the file every time
```

So what I want it to do is create a new line when I want to input a new alias so that it won't smudge all together and make unnecessary errors.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\n` is probably the easiest:

```
with open ("/user/.bashrc","a+") as f1:
   f1.write(new_alias + " " + alias_command + "\n")
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid for not thinking about it, thank you XD